# Node.js named pipe C#

Tags: named-pipes

I am trying to make a NodeJS program and a c# communicate but I can't get the communication working. I think it used to work before but after an update, I needed to change the NodeJS code, and since I really don't have much experience with NodeJS I probably messed up something there. Help would be appreciated.

NodeJS code:

```js
logCommand(req, resp) {
        const { command } = req;

        var PIPE_NAME = "mypipe";
        var PIPE_PATH = "\\\\.\\pipe\\" + PIPE_NAME;
        var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {

            stream.on('data', function (c) {
            });

            stream.on('end', function () {
                server.close();
            });

        });
        server.on('close', function () {
            server.close();
        })

        server.listen(PIPE_PATH, function () {
        })

        let logfile = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(config.Config.App.filesPath, 'CairossRun.txt'), {
            flags: 'a',
            autoClose: true
        });
        let text1 = `error\n\n`

        if (resp.win_lose === 1) {
            text1 = `Run: Succes\nTypeOfReward: NoRune\nEndOfTransmission\n\n`;
            const rewards = resp.changed_item_list ? resp.changed_item_list : [];
            if(rewards){
                rewards.forEach(reward => {
                  if (reward.type === 8) {
                      text1 = `Run: Succces\nTypeOfReward: Rune\nRuneType: ${JSON.stringify(reward.info.rank)}\nRuneSlot: ${JSON.stringify(reward.info.slot_no)}\nRuneSet: ${JSON.stringify(reward.info.set_id)}\nRuneStars: ${JSON.stringify(reward.info.class)}\nEndOfTransmission\n\n`;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            text1 = `Run: Failed\nnEndOfTransmission\n\n`;
        }
        server.on('connection', function (stream) {
            stream.write(text1);
        })
        server.on('drain', function (stream) {
            stream.write(text1);
        })
```

C# code:

```cs
    public bool Connecting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connecting");
        pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "mypipe", PipeDirection.In);
        try
        {
            pipe.Connect(5000);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {

        }
        if (pipe.IsConnected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connected");

            fileReader = new StreamReader(pipe);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```